# Border for Wordpress post loop, grid using Bootstrap

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

Have a loop going with 3 posts per row. Having trouble with making a border wrap around each individual post. Instead, it's making a border that covers the top post extending to bottom post on the grid. See [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/burqp0lpqxmx99l/Screenshot%202017-05-04%2018.11.05.png?dl=0)

I tried adding a different class name other than generic selector used here, but didn't seem to work. Any advice would be appreciated. First project using Wordpress with Bootstrap. Using Sass for styling, hence the section divs. Thanks in advance!

```css
.col-sm-4 {
        border: 1px solid gray;
    }
```

```html
<section id="blog-section">
    <div class="container">   
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h1>Blog Title</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="container">    
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                <?php $i = 1 ?>
                <?php $posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
));
                foreach ($posts as $post) : start_wp(); ?>
                <?php if ($i == 1): ?>

                <a class="perm_link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    <div class="blog-image image-responsive"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?></div></a>
                <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                <span class="shortlink">
                    <?php the_shortlink("Read More"); ?>
                </span>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if($i == 3){$i = 1;} else {$i++;} ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>

<div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                <?php $i = 1 ?>
                <?php $posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
));
                foreach ($posts as $post) : start_wp(); ?>
                <?php if ($i == 2): ?>
                <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                <div class="blog-image image-responsive"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?></div>
                <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                <span class="shortlink">
                    <?php the_shortlink("Read More"); ?>
                </span>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if($i == 3){$i = 1;} else {$i++;} ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                <?php $i = 1 ?>
                <?php $posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
));
                foreach ($posts as $post) : start_wp(); ?>
                <?php if ($i == 3): ?>
                <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                <div class="blog-image image-responsive"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?></div>
                <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                <span class="shortlink">
                    <?php the_shortlink("Read More"); ?>
                </span>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if($i == 3){$i = 1;} else {$i++;} ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying Bootstrap's CSS is generally a no-no. Anytime you reuse that `.col-sm-4` anywhere on your site, you're going to see that `border: 1px solid gray;` show up. Firstly you'll want to create a class like: `<div class="custom-border">` or something of that sort, and then write something like this in your custom css file:

```
.custom-border { border: 1px solid grey; }
```

This way you're not stepping on bootstrap's columns (and a bunch of other parts of your site too).

Also if you want to write CSS that wraps each individual post, you're going to want to apply your custom class within that particular `foreach` loop.

`.col-sm-4` is simply declaring the column, which is 4 across, and spans top to bottom in the grid. Hence your issue. So you'd want something like:

```
<div class="container">    
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                <?php $i = 1 ?>
                <?php $posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
));
                foreach ($posts as $post) : start_wp(); ?>
                <?php if ($i == 1): ?>

                <a class="custom-border perm_link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    <div class="blog-image image-responsive"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?></div>
                </a>
                <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                <span class="shortlink">
                    <?php the_shortlink("Read More"); ?>
                </span>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if($i == 3){$i = 1;} else {$i++;} ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here I've added that `custom-border` class to the `<a>` tag within the `foreach`.

Comment: Thank you for that! My thinking was the col tag would include the entire post, but was short sighted. And yes, aware that would be terrible to use Bootstrap's classes, but I'm coding with Sass and would be nested under section tag, which would avoid conflicts on other pages / sections. 

My final solution is posted below.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the response from s0rfi949, I was applying border to wrong div. Instead, wrapped post in new div outside of the a tag, as this wasn't covering the whole post.

As mentioned in original post, I'm using Sass, so the class would be nested under section. (Forgot to note that in original css example)

```css
#blog-section{
 .custom-border {
        border: 2px solid black;
    }
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">    
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                <?php $i = 1 ?>
                <?php $posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
));
                foreach ($posts as $post) : start_wp(); ?>
                <?php if ($i == 1): ?>

                <div class="custom-border">
                    <a class="perm_link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                        <div class="blog-image image-responsive"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?></div></a>
                    <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                    <span class="shortlink">
                        <?php the_shortlink("Read More"); ?>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if($i == 3){$i = 1;} else {$i++;} ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
```